# Should I divide my frontend code into common and page-specific parts?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I have quite an old-fashioned webapp which has different urls and pages are rendered mainly on server site for each, like `/contacts`, `/orders`, `/orders/123456`.

I am thinking about breaking client code into common and page-specific parts as files, so that I would have a list of files like this:

```
/js/common.js

/js/login_page.js
/js/contacts_page.js
/js/orders_page.js
/js/orderview_page.js
...
```

This way I would have two links in the page - one for common part and one for the current page code.

I think that it can make the pages load faster because of not having to load the code that is not related to a current page, but only what's needed is loaded.

Though, there is a trend to bundle the whole set of files into one which makes first load longer but then others pages code load instantly as it's already in cache.

```
/js/app.bundle.js
```

What strategy should I choose and what factors can influence on the decision?

Comment: The thing, afaik, is that making only one bundle you're saving an http request, which should be faster than making two requests -one for common code and one for specific- even if the amount of code is bigger. However, this really depends on how browsers handle concurrent requests, the number of requests to vendor scripts and other resources your page is doing and the domain configuration from which your page loads the resources. One strategy may be faster in old browsers and slower in up-to-date browsers, I belive. However, difference between one or two bundles is marginal.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have 2 options here. First one is to use individual JS files for each of your page while the second option is to combine all the files together.
In either case, if the files are cached in the browser what matters is the initial load time.

The delay in loading different files is mainly because of the size of the files while some amount of time is wasted in overhead involved in downloading each onne of the file separately.
So if you need 10 files to be download for a particular page then combining all those 10 files would be slightly faster than downlading 10 different files together. However if you are clubbing 100 files but need only 10 out of them then downloading those 10 files separately would be a better option.

I would say that you'll need to use a mixed approach wherein you definitely combine the files together but not all of them in one single bundle. May be divide your files in different groups based on the requirement. Lets say you order page needs 5 JS files(orders_page.js, orderview_page.js etc) then combine all these together. Similarly files related to contact can be clubbed together. You download them as and when users access those specific pages.

Having said that, you should still maintain you codebase separately and look for some library which can 'build' your code for production. Something that optimizes the variable names(shortens it), removes the whitespaces and combines the JS files as per your grouping. Readability would be effected in production but it will make things a lot faster and you can still work on clean/readable code in dev environment.